# Getting quosures to work inside a map call

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, tidyeval

I'm struggling to get quosures to work inside a `map` call.

Some toy data:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
   g1 = letters[1:2] %>% 
     rep(each = 3),
   g2 = letters[3:5] %>% 
     rep(times = 2),
   y = runif(6)
  )
```

I can get this function to work, where I `enquo` a variable before I pass it to `group_by`:

```
sum1 <- function(df, g){

 g <- enquo(g)

 df %>% 
   group_by(!! g) %>% 
   summarize(
     mu = y %>% 
       mean
     )
  }
```

Calling this function

```
 sum1(df, g2)
```

gets me the expected result. But if I want to `map` over multiple grouping variables, (ie `g1` & `g2`)

```
 str_c("g", 1:2) %>% 
   map(
    function(i)
      sum1(df, i)
   )
```

Returns the error

```
  Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) : 
   Column `i` is unknown
```

How can I set up `quosures` in a `map` call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `group_by_at` and it can take a string as argument

```
library(tidyverse)
sum1 <- function(df, grps){

 map(grps, ~ 
           df %>%
              group_by_at(.x) %>%
              summarise(mu = mean(y))
              )

              }

sum1(df, str_c("g", 1:2))
#[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  g1       mu
#  <chr> <dbl>
#1 a     0.440
#2 b     0.469

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  g2       mu
#  <chr> <dbl>
#1 c     0.528
#2 d     0.592
#3 e     0.243
```

---

Regarding the usage of parameters with quosure in function, it is not clear whether it should be a single parameter or multiple parametr

In case if we are going with the string as argument, convert it to symbol (`sym`) and then evaluate (`!!`)

```
sum2 <- function(df, grps){


 map(grps, ~ 
           df %>%
              group_by(!! rlang::sym(.x)) %>%
              summarise(mu = mean(y))
              )

              }

sum2(df, str_c("g", 1:2))
#[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  g1       mu
#  <chr> <dbl>
#1 a     0.440
#2 b     0.469

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  g2       mu
#  <chr> <dbl>
#1 c     0.528
#2 d     0.592
#3 e     0.243
```

---

Another with quosure to pass multiple groups would be

```
sum3 <- function(df, ...){

   gs <- enquos(...)
   map(gs, ~ 
         df %>%
            group_by(!! .x) %>%
            summarise(mu = mean(y)))


              }
sum3(df, g1, g2)
#[[1]]
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  g1       mu
#  <chr> <dbl>
#1 a     0.440
#2 b     0.469

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  g2       mu
#  <chr> <dbl>
#1 c     0.528
#2 d     0.592
#3 e     0.243
```

Answer (score 0):

```
str_c("g", 1:2) %>% 
  syms() %>%
  map(sum1, df = df)
```

`syms()` turns `character`s into symbols (expected by `sum1`).

<s>Rewriting `map(function(i) sum1(df, i))` as `map(sum1, df = df)` prevents unwanted evaluation of the promise `i` that happens when `sum1` is wrapped in another function.</s>

Rewriting `map(function(i) sum1(df, i))` as `map(sum1, df = df)` allows to pass the symbols `g1` and `g2` directly to `sum1()`, rather than the symbol `i`.

(Alternatively, `str_c("g", 1:2) %>% syms() %>% map(function(i) sum1(df, !! i))` or `str_c("g", 1:2) %>% map(function(i) sum1(df, !! sym(i)))` work, where `!!` unquotes `i` before passing it to `sum1()`.
(Actually this is a bit oversimplified: unquoting doesn't happen *before*, but when you do `enquo(g)` in the body of `sum1`).